# When to delete class pointer from array

Tags: c++, class, delete-operator

I have a list of pointer  `object  *lst[200];`

I use this to add one to it:

```
object a = new object();
a->id = current_amount;
lst[current_amount] = a;
current_amount++;
```

now I want to add a function delete it:

I simply want to remove this element from array: (I store an id use it to  delete it)

```
    void delete(object *elem)
    {
        if(!elem)
          return;
       for (int i = elem->id ; i < current_amount - 1;i++)
       {
            lst[i] = lst[i + 1];
       }

    }
```

Question: When to call `delete elem`? The code above doesn't free the memory at all...

Comment: `delete elem;` inside the function.

Comment: The only right time to delete a pointer is when that pointer is the last copy you have. If you find it hard to answer that question with the code you have, then your code is badly designed.

Comment: It looks like you're using `id` and `current_amount` to keep track of an element's position in the list and total number of elements respectively. If so, you should also decrement the `id` of each element within the loop and `current_amount` after the loop within the deleter function. Otherwise a subsequent call to the function might end up accessing invalid elements. A real fix would be to rethink your design and make use of container classes, such as `vector` or `list` from the standard library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void deleteElem(object *elem) // you can't call your function 'delete'
    {
        if(!elem)
          return;

       for (int i = elem->id ; i < current_amount - 1;i++)
       {
            lst[i] = lst[i + 1];
       }

       delete elem; // this free's the memory

    }
```

Comment: You are freeing the pointer, then immediately trying to access the id field in the for loop.

Comment: It is still a little bit dangerous to blindly delete the pointer, maybe a null check is worthwhile? Of course, if you were especially concerned you should probably just use smart pointers and skip this whole exercise (assuming it isn't hw, etc).

Comment: @shenles, there is a check at the begining

Answer (score 0):

Since the code above isn't C++, here's some that is:

```
std::list<std::unique_ptr<object>> lst;
```

and the methods `erase`, `push_back`, `push_front`.

Comment: Oh please, let people learn basics about memory before they start using smart pointers and other fancy stuff

Comment: @LuchianGrigore True, however C++ code that does not fully utilize the entire set of facilities of the language and/or library, and may even be written in a less than ideally object oriented way (a.k.a. looks more like C, but still follows C++ syntax and other rules) is still C++. I don't see anything in the above code that makes it "not C++". Not the best C++ code, certainly, but it's still C++.

Comment: @Luchian Grigore, no, but stl is not c++ either, it's just a nice bonus, not nessecerily available on OP's platform

Comment: @aleguna The `std` (not stl) is fully defined in the C++ Standard.

Comment: @twalberg how about the `object a = new object();` part? Is that still C++?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore Valid point, as the intention was likely `object *a = ...`, but I don't know that that's not just a typo, either. And it's certainly not valid C.

Comment: @Luchian Grigore, I know, but it doesn't mean that it's available everywhere. When I write software for my toaster, I use a naked C++ compiler without any libs at all, but it's still C++, not java or haskell.

Comment: @twalberg I never said it was C... And regardless, the code was likely pasted from memory, so it's not a copy-paste issue. Which means it's not representative for a particular situation. It's not narrowed down, and it's blatantly wrong. I'm suggesting a better alternative.

Comment: @aleguna This is my last message as this isn't productive. You can either take something from it or not. The most important thing that you should learn is that **a compiler doesn't dictate the language**. Compilers can be wrong. So valid C++ is determined by the specs (the standard) not by some shady compiler (or even well-known one). So yes, "I use a naked C++ compiler without any libs at all, but it's still C++" - if your compiler doesn't obey the standard, you can write non-C++ code. Call it whatever you want.